# How to filter search from table in pagination laravel?

Tags: jquery, search, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5. I have displayed data from database in tables:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="mytable" >
       <thead>
           <tr>
             <td><strong>#</strong></td>
             <td class="text-center col-lg-1"><strong>Seksyen</strong></td>
             <td class="text-center col-lg-3"><strong>Kategori</strong></td>
             <td class="text-center col-lg3-2"><strong>Pangkat</strong></td>
             <td class="text-center col-lg-5"><strong>Nama</strong></td>
             <td class="text-center col-lg-1"><strong>No Personal</strong></td>
             <td class="text-center"><strong>Lihat Rekod</strong></td>
             <td class="text-center"><strong>Edit</strong></td>
           </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
           @foreach($itemregistrations as $index => $value)                                               
           <tr>
              <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $value->sectionname }}</td>
              <td>{{ $value->categoryname }}</td>
              <td>{{ $value->operasiname }}</td>
              <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
              <td>{{ $value->Nobadan }}</td>
              <td class="text-center">
             <a href="{{ route('viewProfil',$value->ItemRegistrationID) }}"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="view profil"></i></a></td>
            @can('Edit Pegawai','Edit APR','Edit KTA','Edit PTK')
            <td class="text-center"><a href="{{ route('editProfil',$value->ItemRegistrationID) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="edit profil"></i></a></td>
            @endcan
        </tr>
      @endforeach  
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <ul class="pagination pull-right">
       {{ $itemregistrations->links() }}
  </ul>
```

The output html:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="mytable">
                                            <thead>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td><strong>#</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-center col-lg-1"><strong>Seksyen</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-center col-lg-3"><strong>Kategori</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-center col-lg3-2"><strong>Pangkat</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-center col-lg-5"><strong>Nama</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-center col-lg-1"><strong>No Personal</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-center"><strong>Lihat Rekod</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-center"><strong>Edit</strong></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                        <tbody>

                                                <tr style="display: table-row;">
                                                    <td>1</td>
                                                    <td>B8</td>
                                                    <td>KAKITANGAN</td>
                                                    <td>EXEC</td>
                                                    <td>AB SAUFI</td>
                                                    <td>I10111</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/3"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="view profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                            <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_profil/3"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="edit profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                        </tr>

                                                <tr style="display: table-row;">
                                                    <td>2</td>
                                                    <td>C4</td>
                                                    <td>KAKITANGAN</td>
                                                    <td>EXEC</td>
                                                    <td>ABBAS HALIM</td>
                                                    <td>I38222</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/38"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="view profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                            <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_profil/38"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="edit profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                        </tr>

                                                <tr style="display: table-row;">
                                                    <td>3</td>
                                                    <td>S2</td>
                                                    <td>KAKITANGAN</td>
                                                    <td>CLERK</td>
                                                    <td>LAILA GHANI</td>
                                                    <td>I9394</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/41"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="view profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                            <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_profil/41"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="edit profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                        </tr>

                                                <tr style="display: table-row;">
                                                    <td>4</td>
                                                    <td>S1</td>
                                                    <td>KAKITANGAN</td>
                                                    <td>CLERK</td>
                                                    <td>AWANG JALIL</td>
                                                    <td>I377635</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/94"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="view profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                            <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_profil/94"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="edit profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                        </tr>

                                                <tr style="display: table-row;">
                                                    <td>5</td>
                                                    <td>R3</td>
                                                    <td>KAKITANGAN</td>
                                                    <td>EXEC</td>
                                                    <td>HAWA HASSAN</td>
                                                    <td>I017017</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/99"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="view profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                            <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_profil/99"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="edit profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                        </tr>

                                                <tr style="display: table-row;">
                                                    <td>6</td>
                                                    <td>S1</td>
                                                    <td>KAKITANGAN</td>
                                                    <td>CHIEF</td>
                                                    <td>SHAHRIL KHALID</td>
                                                    <td>I217315</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/108"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="view profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                            <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_profil/108"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="edit profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                        </tr>

                                                <tr style="display: table-row;">
                                                    <td>7</td>
                                                    <td>S1</td>
                                                    <td>KAKITANGAN</td>
                                                    <td>EXEC</td>
                                                    <td>AZRI DAUD</td>
                                                    <td>I022772</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/119"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="view profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                            <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_profil/119"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="edit profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                        </tr>

                                                <tr style="display: table-row;">
                                                    <td>8</td>
                                                    <td>D2</td>
                                                    <td>KAKITANGAN</td>
                                                    <td>CHIEF</td>
                                                    <td>LOLA FARID</td>
                                                    <td>I015371</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/132"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="view profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                            <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_profil/132"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="edit profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                        </tr>

                                                <tr style="display: table-row;">
                                                    <td>9</td>
                                                    <td>A</td>
                                                    <td>KAKITANGAN</td>
                                                    <td>CHIEF</td>
                                                    <td>ALI AHMAD</td>
                                                    <td>I90111</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/157"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="view profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                            <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_profil/157"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="edit profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                        </tr>

                                                <tr style="display: table-row;">
                                                    <td>10</td>
                                                    <td>B6</td>
                                                    <td>KAKITANGAN</td>
                                                    <td>EXEC</td>
                                                    <td>HANI MUHAMMAD</td>
                                                    <td>I2881</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/194"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="view profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                            <td class="text-center"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_profil/194"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="edit profil"></i></a></td>
                                                                                                        </tr>

                                        </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

I used jquery script for searching in html table like this to perform the filter function:

```
<script>
 // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#search").keyup(function(){
 _this = this;

 // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
 $.each($("#mytable tbody tr"), function() {
   if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
      {  
       $(this).hide();
      }
   else
     {
      $(this).show();
     }
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

I had display the data tables in pagination. The search can do filter but only what display in the page. It doesn't search through all data in other pagination page.

How to modify the code to search through all pagination pages?

Comment: Will you include the html output in your question? Thanks.

Comment: To search through all the records you need to have all the records into table, then you can use datatable's searching

Comment: All the records are very long, so I paginate the table. Is there any way to search pagination table?

Comment: as per my previous researches, i didn't find a way to search in paginated table. Instead please use db search.

Comment: is it using ajax? i have been trying  a few but not working...this one using jquery from table easier but not working with pagination